# Closed-form of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the closed-form of the following series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}\ ?$$

From a different approach I got the answer as $(1-x)^{-1/2}$, by using the fact that $\binom{2n}{n}(2)^{-2n}$  is approximately $\dfrac1{\sqrt{n\pi}}$. I just want to know whether this can be directly solved without using any approximation. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it should start from $n=1$

Comment: [Polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: You solution seems incorrect, as the sum converges to $0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, while $(1-x)^{-1/2}$ converges to $1$.

Comment: It can't be $(1-x)^{1/2}$ because the power series for that has rational coefficients.